# "dotnet tool update -g app" updates to 0.0.76 which doesn't support studio

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to update app so I can use ServiceStack studio but it doesn't seem to want to update to latest version.

```
> dotnet tool update -g app
Tool 'app' was reinstalled with the latest stable version (version '0.0.76').

> app -version
Version: 0.0.76
ServiceStack: 5.8
Framework: .NET Core 3.1.5
OS: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
Chromium: 81.0.4044.113

new version available, update with:

  dotnet tool update -g app
```

How can I get latest version that supports studio?

Comment: `0.0.76` is the latest, what happens when you run `app open studio`?

Comment: OK it actually works, I was just getting thrown off by it saying 5.8 and a newer version was available